Make the individual bars that share a common observation/entry appear side-by-side instead of being scattered according to axis label in R
Basically, I have a dataset with three variables im interested in plotting. One is called subgroup which has the name of subgroups that the strains belong to. At least two of them share the same subgroup. Currently, when I bar plot them,and fill by subgroup I get coloured bars accroding to the subgroups but they dont appear next to eachother (and instead do by strain name in alphabetical order). I want a barplot that has any strain from the same subgroup together.
Heres the code:
ggplot(data = Phylogeny_Pseudomonads_BasicGenomeData,
       aes(x= Strain,
           y= genome_size_in_Mb))+
  aes(fill = Subgroups, y= genome_size_in_Mb, x=Strain)+
  labs(title = "Genome Sizes Across Strains",
       x= "Strain", y= "Genome Size in Mb")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width = 0.5)

heres what I have:
enter image description here
dput():
structure(list(Subgroups = c("Jessenii", "fluorescens", "fluorescens", 
"gessardii", "gessardii", "fragi", "fragi"), `Species Name + Strain` = c("Pseudomonas umsongensis", 
"Pseudomonas fluorescens", "Pseudomonas extremaustralis", "Pseudomonas sp.", 
"Pseudomonas fluorescens", "Pseudomonas psychrophila", "Pseudomonas taetrolens"
), Strain = c("GO16", "SBW25", "DSM17835", "Ag1", "R8", "HA4", 
"LMG2336"), `refseq assembly` = c("GCF_008824165.1", "GCF_000009225.2", 
"GCF_900102035.1", "GCF_000006765.1", "GCF_000297195.3", "GCF_000282975.1", 
"GCF_900104825.1"), genome_size_in_Mb = c(7.4, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 
7, 5.2, 4.9), `chromosome number` = c("2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"-", "-"), `GC content` = c(59, 60.5, 60.5, 66.5, 61, 56.5, 58
), `Number of CDS genes` = c(6441, 5974, 6000, 5572, 6307, 4666, 
4360), `Genes number` = c(6698, 6154, 6228, 6708, 6440, 4823, 
4507)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))


Please post your sample data as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture. dput() is the nicest way to share sample data, dput(Phylogeny_Pseudomonads_BasicGenomeData[1:10, ]) will give R code to recreate the first 10 rows of your data. Please make sure that the small sample of data you choose to share illustrates the problem.

That said, this sounds like a simple fix. You have x= Strain, which puts the Strain column on the x-axis. It sounds like you want the subgroups, not the strain, on the x axis, so try x = Subgroups instead? Or, are you saying that you want to re-order the strains on the x axis to make sure subgroups are next to each other?

@GregorThomas Yes, I want to reorder the strains on the x-axis to make sure the subgroups are next to each other. so that all subgroups of e.g. jessenii are next to eachother instead of what they are now. Thank you for the dput() tip!

This groups the bars for Strain in Subgroups:
ggplot(data = Phylogeny_Pseudomonads_BasicGenomeData, 
       aes(fill = Strain, x = Subgroups, group = Strain, y = genome_size_in_Mb), color = "white") +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = .8, preserve = "single"), 
           stat = "identity",
           width = .8)


Your data already appears to be in a good order for this--if not you can sort it by Subgroups and then by Strain with arrange(Subgroups, Strain) (using library(dplyr)). When your data is in the correct order, we can use forcats::fct_inorder to convert Strain to a factor with the levels in the order they appear in the data. We can do this in-line in the ggplot code. I also cleaned up the code a little to reduce repetition and, stylistically, I like to have all the geoms first, then the scales, then the labels:
ggplot(
  data = Phylogeny_Pseudomonads_BasicGenomeData,
  aes(x = forcats::fct_inorder(Strain),
      y = genome_size_in_Mb,
      fill = Subgroups)
  ) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  labs(title = "Genome Sizes Across Strains", x = "Strain", y = "Genome Size in Mb")


